# Parse.com Local data store

Tags: android, parse-platform

how does the parse local data store work with respect to updating. If I call they query and then pin it to my local data store for the second time, would it only pin the new objects or would it pin all of them again?

Thanks

Comment: what you tries so far?

Comment: I get the query and then pin all in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are querying an item and then modifying it and saving it again it will update the current item in the data base. If you are querying an item and creating a new Item with the information of the old item it will create a second item on the database.

Answer (score 0):

All the ParseObjects are saved to the Local Datastore when you pin the result of a query, hence not updated. Here's what you should probably do:

1. Pick a **key** to use when pinning/unpinning your objects.
2. Unpin all objects with that **key**. `ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("your_key")`
3. Pin your resultant list of ParseObjects with a **key**. `objects.pinAllInBackground("your_key")`

This will unpin all objects saved with that specific key and pin all your new objects, hence an update is performed.

Comment: my thing is that I have lots of info in the server and I dont want it to update all of it every time just update if I add anything

Comment: This can go 2 ways. Firstly, if you're sure your existing data will not be updated (such as a field) and you will only add new data, you could count the number of objects in the datastore and in the Parse class, subtract them an if the answer I greater than 0, set that as your limit using query.setLimit(number)

Comment: Secondly, if your existing data could be potentially updated, then this is a cumbersome task. You might go about this by comparing the objectIDs of the objects in the datastore and those in Parse.